# Add a new column in CSV file by using existing columns

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I receive a list of user accounts in form of a CSV file from an external system and am trying to add the `samAccountname` to a new one.

The CSV look like this:

```
Name;Surname;EMail;Company;Position;Department;Manager
Testie;Testface;testie-testface@domain.bla;Our Company;His or her Position;A fancy department name;The Manager
```

What I am trying to do is to add a new column with the user's `SamAccountName` so I can properly use the list it in my AD later on. Until now I found half a dozen approaches but none wants to do it correctly.

The closest that I get is to have some code run without an error but no effect in the CSV or the wrong effect in the CSV file. I have tried `foreach` and `Foreach-Object` methods but I can not get where I want. Since I am not an expert in PowerShell, I can not troubleshoot it myself. Can anyone here help?

This is one of my approaches:

```
$CSVData = Import-Csv 'C:\test.csv' -Delimiter ';'
foreach ($f in $CSVData) {
    $sam = Get-ADUser -Filter "GivenName -eq '$f.Name' -and SurName -eq '$f.Surname'" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'SamAccountName' 

    $CSVData | Select-Object *, @{Name = 'samAccountName'; Expression = { $sam } } 
} | Set-Content 'C:\output.csv'
```

I could post more but I think it is not helpful, my guess is that it would have to be rewritten anyway.

Comment: Re your attempt to use `$f.Name` and `$f.Surname` inside `"..."`: Only variables _by themselves_ can be embedded as-is in [expandable strings (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), e.g. `"foo $var"` or `"foo $env:USERNAME"`. To embed _expressions_ or even commands, you must enclose them in `$(...)`. Notably, this includes property and index access (e.g., `"foo $($var.property)"`, `"foo $($var[0])"`) as well as method calls (e.g. `"foo $($var.Replace('x', 'y'))"`).

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 main issues with your code:

1. You can't pipe after a [language keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_keywords?view=powershell-7.3), in this case, the `foreach` statement.
2. `'$f.Name'` and `'$f.Surname'` can't expand in your filter string, you could use the [Subexpression operator `$( )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#call-operator-) to allow these values to expand as shown below.

```bash
$expression = {
    (Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(givenName=$($_.Name))(surname=$($_.Surname)))").samAccountName
}
Import-Csv 'C:\test.csv' -Delimiter ';' |
    Select-Object *, @{ N = 'samAccountName'; E = $expression } |
    Export-Csv 'C:\output.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Sorry for the deplay in my reply, has been really busy here.

I can not follow much of your description as PowrShell and programming are not my every-day-business but I understand your code ... most of it. Thanks for provoding it.

Unfortunately it does not produce any result. The resulting CSV ends with an empty comma where the samAccountName should be:

Name;Surname;EMail;Company;Position;Department;Manager,samAccountName
Testie,Testface,testie-testface@domain.bla,Our Company,His or her Position,A fancy department name,The Manager,

Something wrong with the Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter?

Comment: @HtHNightwolf does `Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '(&(givenName=Testie)(surName=Testface))'` find any result? if no then you're giving the wrong GivenName or Surname. The filter used in this answer is correct as long as the data being fed is correct.

Comment: I gave that a try but when I use the full Syntax, it does not find any results.

But When I use Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '((givenName=Testie))' alone, it finds the correct results. When I use Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '((surName=Testface))', there are no results.

Maybe it is not possible to use Get-ADUser with surname?

I double-checked even that the Surname matches. When I do
`Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '(&(givenName=Testie))'` then the result shows correctly the user with it's attribute `Surname           : Testface`

Comment: @HtHNightwolf the filter `(&(givenname=...)(surname=...))` is correct. Maybe your user has an extra space before or after its surname and thus not meeting the filter condition. I don't know.